# SEO strategy unique ID in URL

Tags: url, seo, uniqueidentifier

What would be the best way for a URL to look like if it should contain an ID and a name?

> ```
> /product/123/screwdriver-black
> /product/screwdriver-black/123
> /product/123-screwdriver-black
> /product/screwdriver-black-123
> ```

Thanks

Comment: @Rushyo Why do you think this should be a CW?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to format pretty URLs for numeric IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851140/best-way-to-format-pretty-urls-for-numeric-ids)

Answer (score 3):

IMO use what SO uses.

```
/product/123/screwdriver-black
```

That way you are still able to access the product 123 via

```
/product/123
```

For example, while SO puts the question name in the link, it is 100% optional. You can still access this question with

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480964
```

Answer (score 0):

as a rule it is best to limit the number of directories, as google is supposed to add weight to pages that are higher level e.g. not nested in multiple folders
so something like /product/123-screwdriver-black would be best

however, In reality i'd use /product/123/screwdriver-black because it is cleaner and having worked on very large ecommerce sites with very good seo rankings i've found it makes little difference to google, as one good inbound link can make a bigger impact than almost any url formatting will.

Comment: "google is supposed to add weight to pages that are higher level" Then would it not be better to have a format like /screwdriver-black-p123 (p for product)?

Answer (score 0):

For ranking I'd suspect there is little or no difference so I'd let other factors dictate.

The numbers are most likely the way a page is identified so should be easy to parse and before content which has no influence on the content (the text for keywords).

Google often truncates the display url in its search results by showing the start and end with the middle removed. So the keywords may work best at the end.

If you change the text in the url you should create a redirect. This can be slightly easier if the static part of the url is first and the variable part last.

Using folders (/) as the delimiter for the id removes the need to use special characters like underscore (_) to distinguish where the id is. Keeping the url easier to read and enter.

Depth of a folder structure does not mean depth in a website, and people often mix them up.

So my bet is on

/thing/345/name-of-thing

Answer (score -1):

The preffered structure is that of significance.

More general to the top, more specific to the bottom.

This is the natural (well, according to G, we could always get into a big philosophical debate on that) linking order.

So, it only makes sense to use

> /product/screwdriver-black/123

Product is more general than screwdriver and 123 is a specific screwdriver.

Makes sense. :)

Comment: I don't know who dv'd you or why, but my feedback is that 'screwdriver-black' in this example is usually a slug that is intended to be unique for product '123'.  If it's not unique, it's probably a mistake.  And that since URL routing probably depends on 'type' ('product') and 'id' ('123'), often putting '123' earlier makes sense.

Comment: I was thinking more about this: usually one wants to have the ID in the URL, in case the slug is edited: "/123/black-screwdriver" becomes "/123/shiny-black-screwdriver" the URL will still direct to the same product.  And having the ID earlier makes it more likely that it will be included in a copy/paste, or in a truncated URL (email wrapping, e.g.), or if a user just prefers copying part of the URL.

Comment: @CarlG Yes, it screwdriver-black isn't a category but the name of the product with id 123, you are right

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend

> /product/screwdriver-black-123/

or

> /product/screwdriver-black/123/

Comment: You should perhaps explain why you would recommend those two solutions, especially since it seems to me both of those would be worse (and I'd lay bets many others would agree).

Comment: I don't know why you think both of them would be worse, would like to know your opinion. The reason why I recommended is that you want to add your keywords before your ids.